# Is there a mailing list especially for Mathematica.StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to have all new questions daily in my email?

Comment: Don't know about "daily", but you can subscribe to the weekly newsletter. There should be a setting in your profile for enabling this feature.

Comment: Thanks 0x4A4d , i have it checked! A daily version would be a nice new future. From what i've seen so far , answers and questions have some hours difference (not a week). So i suppose to be active ,sticking to the site is the most preferable way at the momment.

Comment: I think you can use http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/feeds/?sort=newest to get a feed of the new questions (but you'll have to configure your RSS reader to only check daily)

Comment: Edited title, otherwise [MathGroup](http://smc.vnet.net/mathgroup.html) qualifies too. Which is of course invaluable.

Comment: There is an RSS feed (see the bottom of the pages), and the questions are twittered too.